# using link_to for an external link calling from form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, link-to

I've previously been able to use the following code to link to an external site listed in a form.  However, I can't get it work here.  My controller defines the parameter and it's in the view and in my db/schema (t.string   "website").

Is there something I'm missing?

/show

```
 <p>
   <strong>Website:</strong>
   <%= link_to @woman.website %>
 </p>
```

The website shows up in active admin in my db, but not as a link.  This is what the form partial asks the user to input:
/_form

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :website %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :website,  class: "form-control" %>
 </div>
```

Every time I click the link, it just reloads the same page I'm on.   Would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `href` part, try this

```
<%= link_to @woman.website, @woman.website %>
```